# Laravel resource controller destroy

Tags: laravel, controller, resources, destroy

I'm having trouble using the destroy method from my resource controller.  I know in html you can only POST/GET so I used a hidden value but it comes up with a MethodNotAllowedHttpException error.  Here is my code:

Modal where the Delete Button is:

```
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <form action="/wod/{{$wod->id}}" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                {{ method_field('DELTE') }}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-inverse" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-inverse"><a class="bottom" href="/wod/{{$wod->id}}/edit">Edit</a></button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary navbar-inverse" value="submit" type="submit">Delete</button>
            </form>
          </div>
```

And here is my resource controller:

```
public function destroy(Id $id)
{
    //
    Wod::find($id)->delete();

    return redirect()->action("WodController@index");

}
```

Comment: You have a typo. It should be `DELETE`, not `DELTE`

Comment: wow, thanks hahahaha.  I'll let you know if that works real quick.

Comment: Now I get this: (1/1) ReflectionException
Class App\Http\Controllers\Id does not exist

Comment: Change it to `destroy($id)`

Comment: Realized I don't need Id before $id.  I changed that and forgot to delete it.  Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in    `{{ method_field('DELTE') }}`

it should be   `{{ method_field('DELETE') }}`